# Some windows 7 machines are showing driver update required for most printers?

Tags: deployment, printing, drivers, shared-printers

We have deployed printers using server 2008 however some computers are able to print fine but other just say that they need to update the print driver.

They are all in the same policy. Some request the admin password to install the print driver if you try and print to a printer but others just give an error saying that they are unable to print.

Has anyone got any ideas? All computers are on win 7 32bit.

Many thanks

Fred

p.s. i have tried logging on  with the same user onto different machines and some still give the problem whereas others are ok.

Answer (score 2):

Use a group policy to [point and print restriction](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753269.aspx#BKMK_GPLimitServers).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you already have a GP configured, but, the fact that some pc's are requesting admin credentials and others are just givng an error leads me to beleave some of your users have elavated privleages and others are standard users, and your standard users are not given manage printers access.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However i have tried using a single account on multiple workstations and the results are different. Some work find and others require the driver.

Comment: BTW, is this a mixed environment or Native? Just a thought and healthy reading. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725938.aspx http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753269.aspx http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754699.aspx